# How to set a background color of a Table Cell using iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

While it is of course possible to use `BaseColor`, by default, it offers very limited choices.

I wonder how can i add my own custom color to the document?

```
...
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("some clever text"));
        cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GREEN);
        table.addCell(cell);
...
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Lots of options.

```
BaseColor color = new BaseColor(red, green, blue); // or red, green, blue, alpha
CYMKColor cmyk = new CMYKColor(cyan, yellow, magenta, black); // no alpha
GrayColor gray = new GrayColor(someFloatBetweenZeroAndOneInclusive); // no alpha
```

There's also pattern colors and shading colors, but those are Much Less Simple.

Comment: This solution is for iText 5

Comment: There are also a few color presets like `BaseColor.GREEN` or `BaseColor.RED`

Answer (score 51):

Posting, in hopes someone else will find this response useful.

It seems one can create a new `BaseColor` from WebColor as:

```
BaseColor myColor = WebColors.GetRGBColor("#A00000");
```

Which then can be added as a background as:

```
cell.setBackgroundColor(myColor);
```

Comment: For some reason, my background color is default set to #00FFFF and doesn't want to change to the color I want it set to :/ I think there have been changes to the new itext Sharp but here's what I wrote:  BaseColor bblue = WebColors.GetRGBColor("#006EB6");
            headerCell.BackgroundColor.Equals(bblue);but BackgroundColor is still set to a default.. I could not find setBackgroundColor only BackgroundColor.

Comment: WebColors is obsolete now, do you know of the modern way of doing this or should we just ignore its obsoletedness (as iTextSharp seems to make most of what I use it for obsolete)?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
`cell.setBackgroundColor(new BaseColor(226, 226, 226));`

or:
`cell.setBackgroundColor(WebColors.getRGBColor("#E2E2E2"));` **deprecated**

Answer (score 0):

One more solution is:

```
public static String mColor = "#aa8cc5";
int aa = Integer.parseInt(mColor,16); // base 16
int colorArr = Color.rgb(Color.red(aa),Color.green(aa),Color.blue(aa));
cell1.setBackgroundColor(new BaseColor(colorArr));
```